# How to find, in runtime, the jndi name that was given to my EJB

Tags: ejb-3.0, glassfish-3, java-ee-6

I have a static method that needs to lookup for a EJB instance. The problem is that the JNDI name depends on the name of the JAR where the Interface for the JEB is located. What I'm trying to do is figure it out the name given to the EJB instance of that Interface in runtime.

Is that possible?

Here is the code:

```
private static String JNDI_NAME;

private IRevisionContext getRevisionContext() {
    try {
        if (JNDI_NAME == null) {
            //TODO: find the jndi name for IRevisionContext
        }

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        IRevisionContext revisionContext = (IRevisionContext) ctx.lookup(JNDI_NAME);
        return revisionContext;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This is the name given by the container:

Portable JNDI names for EJB RevisionContextLBean:

- java:global/GRP_UFMS_EAR/auditoria-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/RevisionContextLBean!br.ufms.nti.infra.entidade.audit.IRevisionContext
- java:global/GRP_UFMS_EAR/auditoria-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/RevisionContextLBean

You can also suggest a better way to do so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To determine the running application, use `lookup("java:app/AppName")`
To determine the running module, use `lookup("java:module/ModuleName")`.  There is no way to determine if you are running in a standalone module, though as a heuristic, you could check if appName.equals(moduleName).  There is no way to determine an EJB name, though depending on what you're doing, you might be able to hard-code the EJB name (and interface name), or use [Context.list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) to choose between the available EJBs.